# How to mock node-canvas?

Tags: node.js, canvas, qr-code

I'm using the node-canvas (https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) to generate a qrCode with qr-code-styling and I'm trying to mock it

`import * as nodeCanvas from 'canvas';`
`const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({ nodeCanvas , // this is required ...QR_CODE_OPTIONS, data: opts.QRCodeUrl })`

but when I try to create an unit test
`import * as nodeCanvas from 'canvas';`
`jest.mock('nodeCanvas')`

I got an error from canvas

[image]

Anyone has an idea?

Thx all

Comment: You need to mock the library name or filename, not the name you import it by. Try `jest.mock('canvas')` instead of your current statement.

Comment: Still the issue :s